# CSS Fit font size to mobile devices/smaller screens

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'v noticed, that some webpages fit mobile devices.
I know how to do elements positioning for mobiles, etc.
My problem are fonts. Those mobiledevices, have pretty high screen resolution. And fonts are too small, because of small screen.

Can I somehow larger fonts on smaller screens?

Comment: You can use media queries for larger fonts on smaller screens

Comment: I know, i have media queries for screen resolution. But some of those mobilephones have larger resolution than my Monitor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to target retina display in that case. There is different ways of approaching that. Most likely you are doing a fully responsive site so I would recommend just doing a media query to target retina "hi-res" and set your font-size, margins ect.

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

Source: [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)

Comment: Wow! This one should be good, but let me see it in action! :)

Comment: Thats it, thank you very much. Spent hours of searching.

Comment: Safari doesnot support dpi - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolution

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Media Queries to change the font sizes according the different width of the current screen.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   style-element {
      font-size: 20px;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
   style-element {
     font-size: 10px;
   }
}
```

Have a look at these links:

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: My mobilephone has 1980px width. But screen is small, so I can't fit fonts to width.

Answer (score 0):

This media queries not depends on mobile resolution. It depends on device width
suppose iphone width is vertically 320px and horizontally 480px.
Let's try this code

suppose you have a class

```
 .header{
    font-size:30px;        
 }
```

For mobile
I think your mobile width is 360px*640px 
so try it

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
   .header{
       font-size:25px;
   }        
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
   .header{
       font-size:25px;
   }
```

Comment: My mobilephone has 1980px width. But screen is small, so I can't fit fonts to width.

Comment: tell me your mobile phone brand and model. i think 1980px is screen resolution. This is not width

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note 3, well in landscape its width right? And px is screen resolution right? @media screen and (max-width: 480px). Pixels = resolution :P